# experience with api-like fonts from own server?

Tags: css, google-api, google-font-api

I can see that it's [pretty easy to use google fonts](http://blog.codepen.io/2012/07/18/custom-fonts-in-pens/) by linking in the the google api with `@import` but I was wondering how you could do this without the api somehow. Is there a way to get it on my machine? I'm not familiar with using fonts without an api link.

Basically, is there a way I could use this font without linking the api like so?

Answer (score 0):

use `font-face`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "namefont";
    src: url("namefont.eot");
    src: url("namefont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("namefont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("namefont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("namefont.svg#namefont") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google does not provide an option to directly download all font formats (WOFF, WOFF2, SVG, TTF, EOT) and it is not easy to get all font formats to replicate an experience which works in *all* Browsers.

You can use [localfont.com](http://localfont.com/) which provides all above listed fonts along X-Browser CSS for download and easy implementation on your own server.